# How can I disable capitalized input?

Tags: ruby

How can I prevent user uppercase letters input with

```
user = get.chomp
```

if I don`t want use

```
user.downcase!
```

I want user can`t input uppercase letters

Comment: "Preserve the user's original capitalization" means that capital letters in what the user typed should remain in the input string.  However, the rest of the question asks how to prevent the input of capitalized letters at all.  These two things contradict each other.  Can you please edit the question to be more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that in the following way, getch takes one character at a time.
One caviat: you need to end the string with two returns.
Keep in mind that this is only the console, if you want more or fancier control use a simple GUI framework like eg [Shoes](https://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/) of use a web-interface.

```
require 'io/console'

input, user = "", ""
while input != "\n"
  input = STDIN.getch
  if ('a'..'z').include? input
    print input
    user += input 
  end
end
puts "\nuser = #{user}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify that it's all downcase the easy way is:

```
user = gets.chomp

if (user == user.downcase)
  # All downcase
end
```

You can also use a regular expression:

```
user = gets.chomp

if (user.match(/\A[a-z]\z/)
  # All downcase
end
```

That will let you customize which characters are allowed, like if `_` is acceptable.

You can't prevent them from typing in upper-case letters unless you do a lot of work with something like Curses to process individual keystrokes and assume control over echoing output. This is a ton of work and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Note that Ruby 2.4 is needed for `user == user.downcase` with accented characters.